# how to use angular 7 date pipe within template literal (using back tick) in component not in template

Tags: angular, typescript, angular6

I have `changes.lastUpdatedTime.currentValue` which is `1540460704884` I want to use pipe for date format

e.g.  `{{lastUpdatedTime | date:'short'}}`

How I can use | pipe inside the component.

```
${changes.lastUpdatedTime.currentValue} | date:'short'
```

something like this I want to use.

Code Below -

```
ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.typeLabel && changes.cardLabel && changes.severity) {
      this.title = `[${this.severityName}] ${changes.cardLabel.currentValue}
Type: ${changes.typeLabel.currentValue}
Status changed: ${changes.lastUpdatedTime.currentValue}`;
    }
  }
```

I tried to use as below code but it's not working.

```
${changes.lastUpdatedTime.currentValue.transform(myDate, 'yyyy-MM-dd')};
```

I tried to use this - But it's not working.

```
  ngOnChanges(changes: SimpleChanges): void {
    if (changes.typeLabel && changes.cardLabel && changes.severity) {
      let displayedLastUpdatedTime = new DatePipe().transform(changes.lastUpdatedTime.currentValue);
      this.title = `[${this.severityName}] ${changes.cardLabel.currentValue}
Type: ${changes.typeLabel.currentValue}
Status changed: ${displayedLastUpdatedTime}`;
    }
  }
```

this gives error `"has no exported member 'DatePipe'"`

Thanks

Comment: why not apply the pipe in the html? if you have to do it in the component, you can import the pipe as a function

Comment: My this.title if changing on every change, and I dont have last update time.

Comment: This is a duplicate, I have referred you to one of my answers explaining how to use the date pipe in a component. If you still have an issue after that, create a new question with a [mcve] reproducing the said issue

Comment: @trichetriche This is not duplicate. I still have an issue please check updated the question..

Answer (score -1):

I think, this is what you are looking for.

```
import {DatePipe} from '@angular/common';
let result = new DatePipe().transform(input);
```

here is the working example on [JsFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/2t8y0Lfw/)

Comment: I tried to use this.  It gives me error - has no exported member 'DatePipe'

Comment: I really couldn't understand reason for downvoting. It is a working code.

Comment: check JsFiddle for working example. I kindly ask my downvoters to check the link and either remove downvote or provide eligible answer.

Comment: I think reason could be code doesn't work with angular 6

Comment: then, how does it work for Angular4 and also Angular 7? anyways.